# What does pix[x, y] mean in Python

Tags: python, syntax, tuples

I find a strange statement when I'm reading [PIL document](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm).

> In 1.1.6 and later, load returns a pixel access object that can be
>   used to read and modify pixels. The access object behaves like a
>   2-dimensional array, so you can do:
>
> ```
> pix = im.load()
> print pix[x, y]
> pix[x, y] = value
> ```

What does `pix[x, y]` mean here? It's not slicing syntax because `,` used rather than `:`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
pix[x, y]
```

is the same as

```
t = x, y
pix[t]
```

or

```
t = (x, y)
pix[t]
```

or

```
pix[(x, y)]
```

What you're seeing is a tuple literal inside an item-getting expression, in the same way that I can nest other expressions such as `l[1 if skip else 0]`

Comment: I give this: print(pix[10,200]) and I get this: (156, 158, 157, 255) Why? do I get 4 values?